# r dplyr group_by - by variable content

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I use dplyr group_by function to group my data frame,

and need to be able to group the data, by a column, i don't know the name of the column yet, i need to decide it along the code, so the name can't be hard coded.

for example,

i can't use

```
data %>% group_by(col_name)
```

i need to do somthing like

```
data %>% c <- col_name 
data %>% group_by(c)
```

when i try doing so, it popes error:
Error: unknown variable to group by : c

All the examples I find are for the trevial case when you can hard code the name of the column

[group by example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r)

Same in the r help

Thanks.

Comment: Try `group_by_(.dots = c)`

Comment: And look at `vignette('nse')`.

Answer (score 1):

You would like to look up NSE as others have said in their comments. Using that also requires you to use lazyeval package, and group_by_ function, which allows you to you standard evaluation. So it will look like:

```
data %>% group_by_(lazyeval::interp(~var, var = as.name(c)))
```